# Escape when echoed

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping, echo, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've been trying to submit a plugin for review and I keep having problems with the echo line.
The last version I sent was like this.

```
<option value="">
    <?php _e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    $folder = esc_attr( $folder );
    echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
} ?>
```

And the WordPress response was:

> This is not escaped:
>
> ```
> echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
> ```
>
> $folder MUST be escaped when it's echo'd.

Now I'm ready to submit the code for review again but first I want to make sure I'm correct.

Here the new code

```
<option value="">
    <?php _e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '">' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '</option>';
} ?>
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help, as I'm a bit confused about the (escaped).

Comment: There is never any benefit to redundantly declaring an option's text as its `value` attribute.  It is pure, needless markup bloat. When the text and the value are the same, omit the `value` declatation.  The form submission and javascript will work exactly the same (as intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developer documents, everything must be escaped for security reasons. Here are the escaping function WordPress provides for different data:

```
esc_attr()      // Use on everything else that’s printed into an HTML element’s attribute.
esc_html()      // Use anytime an HTML element encloses a section of data being displayed. This WILL NOT display HTML content, it is meant for being used inside HTML and will remove your HTML.
esc_js()        // Use for inline Javascript.
esc_textarea()  // Use this to encode text for use inside a textarea element.
esc_url()       // Use on all URLs, including those in the src and href attributes of an HTML element.
esc_url_raw()   // Use when storing a URL in the database or in other cases where non-encoded URLs are needed.
wp_kses()       // Use to safely escape for all non-trusted HTML (post text, comment text, etc.)
wp_kses_post()  // Alternative version of wp_kses() that automatically allows all HTML that is permitted in post content.
wp_kses_data()  // Alternative version of wp_kses() that allows only the HTML permitted in post comments.
```

Here is the official documentation if you want to read more into it.

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/escaping/

Comment: Thanks for responding and for the documentation, although I had already been there... Taking into account that documentation, do you think I implemented it correctly?

Comment: Was gonna say the same thing. Anything outputted or imputed must be escaped/sanitized by wp native functions. Your last example seems fine. You might want to make the string translatable also.

Comment: @choseɳ - Yes, your code seems to be escaped well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already found your answer still I have few clarifications in this topic and I have optimized the code with escaping

```
<option value="">
    <?php esc_html_e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '">' . esc_html( $folder ) . '</option>';
} ?>
```

You must escape the options text which will show in the front view then it must be escaped by esc_html. In the first line you can see I have escaped the `_e` function using `esc_html_e` because it is also necessary to escape all the static text.

And lastly for best practice I always use html code in html part and php code in php tag area. Here is the optimized code for better understanding.

```
<option value="">
    <?php esc_html_e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $folder ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $folder ); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

It may take more php tags but it is best practice to place your code as php and html separately. I hope it will help you.